# binding an ng-model attr to a changing object value how to update ng-model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to update testVar1 the ng-model attr for the input.  The value succesfully gets

```
$scope.testVar1 = menuElements[$scope.element.id].value;
```

But when i change the value of

```
 menuElements[$scope.element.id].value;
```

I want testVar1 to update along with its input view
Is this possible? if so what am i doing wrong? I made a function below to try and hard set the code to val = 2 but it was not succesful it seems that the scope variables only update when you build the page(at least the way ive written it)

HTML:

```
<div class="well">
    <label for="{{element.id}}">{{element.info}}:</label>

    <input class="ui-slider" type="range" ng-model="testVar1" ng-change="changeValue(element.id)" name="{{element.id}}" min="{{element.min}}" max="{{element.max}}" id="{{element.id}}"/>
    <button ng-click="setTestValue()">Test</button>
</div>
```

Directive and controller

```
cordovaAngular.directive('myCustomer', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            element: '=',
            elementArray: '='
        },
        templateUrl: elementURL,
        controller: function ($scope) {
            var test = JSON.stringify($scope.elementArray);
            $scope.selectedOption = "Success"
            $scope.testVar1 = menuElements[$scope.element.id].value;
            console.log($scope.testVar1);
            console.log($scope.element.id);
            $scope.changeOption = function (selectedItem) {
                $scope.selectedOption = selectedItem;
                // alert(1);
            }
            $scope.changeValue = function (id) {
                menuElements[id].onChange();
            }
            $scope.setTestValue = function () {

                menuElements[$scope.element.id].value = 2;
                $scope.testVar1.
                console.log($scope.testVar1);

            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Where did you define `menuElements`? Is it a part of some `scope` or just a plain JavaScript variable? You didn't define it anywhere in your snippet.

Comment: is the html you posted the directive template?

Comment: @j.wittwer yes the html is the directive template

Comment: @Vadim It is not in a scope currently it is just plain JS I was just thinking about adding it to a (service, provider, or factory)  would that help?

Comment: @user2958863 Angular can't watch plain JavaScript variables change, it should be the part of some scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `$watch`

Assign `menuElements` to a `$scope`variable and add a `$watch` listener to it.

```
$scope.$watch('menuElements', function(newVal, oldVal){
    // When menuElementes change, update testVar1 here
    $scope.testVar1 = menuElements[$scope.element.id].value;
}, true);
```

The AngularJS [docs for *$watch*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

Comment: Atm the function that updates my menuElements is a regular JS callback function from a java plugin.  is there a way to update variables in a scope with a regular JS function?

Comment: `menuElements` have to be part of `$scope`. It's already a JS variable, so shouldn't be a problem to assign it to scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need `menuElements` to be part of the `scope` in order to be able to watch changes in it. Since your directive has isolated scope, it should be in the scope of your directive. Here is an example of doing it:

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="ctrl" id="ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="element in data.elementArray">{{element.id}} - {{data.menuElements[element.id].value}}</li>
  </ul>
  <div my-customer="" element="data.element" element-array="data.elementArray" menu-elements="data.menuElements"></div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', []).
  controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      elementArray: [{
        id: 'el1',
        info: 'Element Info 1',
        min: 0,
        max: 9
      }, {
        id: 'el2',
        info: 'Element Info 2',
        min: 10,
        max: 19
      }],
      menuElements: { 
        'el1': {
          value: 1
        },
        'el2': {
          value: 15
        }
      }
    };
    $scope.data.element = $scope.data.elementArray[0];
  }]).
  directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      template: '<div class="well">' +
                  '<label for="{{element.id}}">{{element.info}}:</label>' +
                  '<input class="ui-slider" type="range" ng-model="testVar1" ng-change="changeValue(element.id)" name="{{element.id}}" min="{{element.min}}" max="{{element.max}}" id="{{element.id}}"/>' +
                  '<button ng-click="setTestValue()">Test</button>' +
                '</div>',
      scope: {
        element: '=',
        elementArray: '=',
        menuElements: '=' // <= add menuElements to scope
      },
      controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.setTestValue = function() {
          $scope.menuElements[$scope.element.id].value = 5;
        }
      }],
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.$watch(function() { // <= Watch changes of scope.menuElements[scope.element.id].value 
          return scope.menuElements[scope.element.id].value;
        }, function(value) {
          scope.testVar1 = value;
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FLl6pLBdCWAfTbvGSBxQ?p=preview

***Edit:***

If you need to modify `scope` from outside of Angular, you can still do it, by fetching `scope` of DOM element related to that scope:

```
function setValue() {
  var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('ctrl')).scope();
  scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.data.menuElements[scope.data.element.id].value = 7;
  });
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LXwJEtCIxVNgAb5AdJM6?p=preview